# Android - if I make a new version of the app for testing on my own device, should I change versionCode/versionName?

Tags: android

I am not exactly sure when I need to be changing the `versionCode/versionName` values in the manifest file before creating a new .apk and putting it on my own device.

Is it ok not to change them at all if I am just going to be testing on my own phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can keep it the same if you are just testing on your phone.

Actually, the version codes and the version names come in handy when you are actually publishing your application on the market, enabling the users to know which version they have and what is presently available on the market.

But, since for the time being, you are just testing on your own, you can keep that the same. Won't be the cause of any problems.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** No, you don't need to change them

**More Detail:** For testing on your own phone, you'll be fine not changing them. It won't crash anything. Depending on your use of the Emulator you may be testing on your device quite frequently, and that would be a major pain! For me I never change them during testing, and I use my phone for testing pretty much exclusively (I can't stand the emulators).

It would however be wise to change them when you publish apps to the Google Play store in order to accurately represent the updated versions to your customers. They appreciate details like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is not need to change it if you are testing.

If you are putting it in the market and updating it,

Version Code is an integer that should be incremented,
Version Name is the name that will be show on descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times you would like to increment the version to keep track of bugs and on which version the bug was fixed. So mostly for tracking.

Other than that, the version number won't affect.

The only time when you may have trouble is when running a developer build(Installed directly from Eclipse) and running a standalone apk. Only in this case you may require to uninstall the previous app, but even then, the version number won't affect, since it is related to the signature and not the version number.